# I'm having a problem with referencing a dll from a web service

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, service, asmx

I am trying to create a custom web service for Sharepoint 2010. I am using Visual Studio 2010, and following the tutorial found @ 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/egady/archive/2009/03/31/writing-custom-web-services-for-sharepoint.aspx

In either case, I seem to keep running into the same problem:

As per the instructions, I remove the codebehind file for the asmx file, and point that to a custom dll. When I do that however, the new WebService Directive does not seem to want to recognize the new class.

it looks like this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService, WIMSPSvcLib, Version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b057b929ec3836e6" %>
```

I figure the issue is in the Class attribute. The samples are C# based, not VB, and I wonder if there is a syntactical issue there.

My error is simply:

> Could not load type
>   'WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService' from
>   assembly 'WIMSPSvcLib,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b057b929ec3836e6'.

Can anyone suggest as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609154/web-service-could-not-create-type-error-with-type-in-the-gac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following things:

- Is your assembly properly installed
  in the GAC?
- Is    'WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService'
  indeed the    Fully Qualified Name? (i.e. shouldn't it for example be `Class="NamespaceA.NamespaceB.WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService, NamespaceA.NamespaceB.WIMSPSvcLib, ...`

Comment: Okay, yes the assembly is/was registered

Comment: I believe that is the fully qualified name... Looking in the project, under the dll the assembly name is WIMSPSvcLib and the root namespace is the WIMSPSvcLib, the namespace is WIMSPSvcLib and the class name is QueryService. it wouldn't be WIMSPSvcLib.WIMSPSvcLib.WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService would it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it was in fact an issue of me just not repeating the namespaces enough times.

> WIMSPSvcLib.WIMSPSvcLib.QueryService, WIMSPSvcLib,.....

was the proper designation

things are working now

Thanks for the help.

Andrew

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that this is not a forum though, please use the "Post answer" button for actual answers only. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient 
[privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like.